# match font Metrics Ascend/Descent with General Ascent/Descent

Tags: fonts, css

Browsers display an additional spacing around the text elements. 
[Refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550274/automatically-set-line-height-so-that-there-is-no-spacing-at-top-and-bottom?noredirect=1#comment82058210_47550274) to see it in action.

How much spacing it is added, is determined by `HHead Ascent` and `Descent` values as [stated here](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) 
I am trying to update a font to be displayed without upper and bottom spacing, therefore I fixed this values to be the same as `Ascender` and `Descender`. I am using Font Forge.

Before:

[image]ž

After:

[image]

I than use this font in a browser, but to my surprise, the top and bottom spacing is till there.  What am I missing here?